# Why do different GCC 4.9.2 installations give different results for this regex match?

Tags: c++, regex, gcc, c++14

I posted the following code on [ideone](http://ideone.com/uwX850) and [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e62775d39c257dd0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string example{"   <match1>  <match2>    <match3>"};
    std::regex re{"<([^>]+)>"};
    std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> it{example.begin(), example.end(), re, 1};
    decltype(it) end{};
    while (it != end) std::cout << *it++ << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Both sites use GCC 4.9.2. I don't know what compilation arguments ideone uses, but there is nothing unusual in Coliru's.

Coliru doesn't give me the `match1` result:

#### Coliru

```
# g++ -v 2>&1 | grep version; \
# g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC) 
match2
match3
```

#### ideone (and, incidentally, [Coliru's clang 3.5.0 using libc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db830d26223fab33))

```
match1
match2
match3
```

Does my code have undefined behaviour or something? What could cause this?

Comment: Thanks to "[Veritas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3024983/veritas)" for inspiring this question in chat.

Comment: One obvious possibility: Even though they're using the same compiler, they're using different standard libraries.

Comment: Doesn't GCC usually ship with a specific libstdc++ version? Wouldn't something have had to go have gone wrong for the libstdc++ versions to differ between GCC 4.9.2 installations (typically)?

Comment: Hmmmm maybe there was a bug in the libstdc++ package that got fixed via patch upgrade on one machine but not the other?

Comment: Hmmmm... moving the `++` out of `*it++` fixes it in Coliru. Has there been a bug where post-fix `++` on `regex_token_iterator` returns the wrong object? That is, it appears to be returning the object *after* the increment.

Comment: [gcc head](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8Tl6E2bLSHoRrvdz) gives the expected results, probably a `libstdc++` issue.

Comment: Scanning Bugzilla now

Comment: [This sample demonstrates the bug with post-fix increment](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4b722cb9cbcf7ff).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's [a bug in libstdc++'s `regex_token_iterator` copy constructor](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64303), as called by the postincrement operator.  The bug was fixed in December 2014; versions of gcc 4.9 and 5.x released since then will have the fix. The nature of the bug is that the copy of the iterator aliases the target of the copy, leading to the observed behavior.

The workaround is to use preincrement - this is desirable from a microoptimisation point of view as well, as `regex_token_iterator` is a reasonably heavy class:

```
for (; it != end; ++it) std::cout << *it << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 8):

The code is valid.

The only plausible explanation is that the standard library versions differ; although for the most part standard library implementations are shipped with compilers, they can be upgraded independently through, say, a Linux package manager.

In this instance it seems that this is a libstdc++ fault that was fixed late last year:

- [Coliru has `__GLIBCXX__ == 20141030`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a0099afd584c5c4)
- [ideone has `__GLIBCXX__ == 20141220`](http://ideone.com/HL1DJG)

The most likely match on Bugzilla that I can find is [bug 63497](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63497) but, to be honest, I'm not convinced this particular bug was ever fully covered by Bugzilla. [Joseph Mansfield](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150634/joseph-mansfield) [identified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750835/why-do-different-gcc-4-9-2-installations-give-different-results-for-this-regex-m/29751045#comment47634275_29750835) that [these specific symptoms in this specific case are triggered by the post-fix increment](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4b722cb9cbcf7ff), at least.

Comment: Here's the [origin](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/b54ba0cbc4849d8dd28ebb99616e327887182f3d) of `operator++` being implemented and it appears to be correct. This tells me it's probably a bug with the copy constructor (maybe?).